# CSS - Two Divs Side by Side, One takes up as much room as need, other fills rest of width

Tags: css

I'm trying to get two Divs to sit side by side. I want one div to take up as much width as is needed and the other to to take up the remaining width so both divs span 100% width. Is this possible? I've tried floating and a bunch of different positioning settings but I can't find a solution that works. I naturally thought that adding a float: left to the left most element would work, however when you try to add padding/margin/border to the right element the browser wont apply it. Here is some code that I've extended (from an existing answer) to illustrate the problem.

```
<style>
    #foo {
        float: left;
        background: red;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #bar {
        background: green;
        border: solid 1px blue;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>   
<div>
    <div id="foo">foo</div>
    <div id="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```

If you open this code up in a browser you'll notice that the bar div isn't padded, and the border isn't applied to it... I have no idea why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0815.htm

Comment: Absolute positioning is an idea if you don't mind that.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial but it assumes a fixed-width left navigation panel. I'm trying to make it so the left navigation can expand as much as needed, and then the div beside that will fill in the remaining space.

Comment: @Casey Hope - Doesn't absolute positioning require that you assign each piece a certain width to work?

Comment: You can use negative margins to achieve this: See http://www.alistapart.com/d/negativemargins/ex3.htm and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/

Comment: I don't think you can use negative margins here because I'm not sure what the width of the side bar is going to be. I might just have to bite the bullet and specify a width for my side bar. I didn't think it would be this hard to do something so basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use a table, set the whole table width to 100% and then each of the rows without a width, like so:

`<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div>DIV INFO LEFT</div></td>
    <td><div>DIV INFO RIGHT</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>`

Comment: Using a table is not a *semantic* way. But even today many web developers don't really care about semantic markup. We cannot say that this is a *bad* way if it works, it's only a *deprecated and ugly* way.

Comment: I've tried this too. However in the left table cell any text you put in there will be wrapped word for word. Is there a way to prevent the text-wrapping? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MvanGeest how can a way be deprecated and ugly and still not bad?

Comment: That wont wrap it because the columns have no width's set, so it automatically goes with the flow, for lack of a better term, and in my scripting, I've learned not to focus on semantics because when you get into complex PHP scripts, semantics are the first thing to fly out the window.

Comment: Even though this solution did not end up working for me (I ended up using DIVs and specifying a width for one of them) I marked it as the answer because it is closest solution to the original question I asked.

Comment: @MvanGeest Using tables is bad for more than semantic reasons.  Table content isn't displayed until the entire table's HTML has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
<style>
    #foo {
        float: left;
        background: red;
    }
    #bar {
        background: green;
    }
</style>   
<div>
    <div id="foo">foo</div>
    <div id="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```

http://pastehtml.com/view/19ldeqq.html

Comment: I thought this would work too, however when you try to add padding/margin/border to the bar div, it wont be applied. I've updated my question to reflect this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another downside is that if the content in #bar is taller than the content in #foo, the content in #bar will wrap underneath the content #foo.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/202mr6co/) is using javascript, but it is the only way I have found to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = shouldNotBeThisHard;
        window.onresize = shouldNotBeThisHard;
        function shouldNotBeThisHard() {
            var j = document.getElementById('divThatYouWantAllOf');
            var k = document.getElementById('divForRestOfScreen');
            var jh = 0;
            if (j)
                jh = j.clientWidth;
            var h = (window.innerWidth - (jh + 30));
            k.style.width= h + "px";
        }
</script>
```

with the HTML looking like this:

```
<div id="divForRestOfScreen" style="float:left;overflow:auto;">
    asdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
    sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
    sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds
    dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
    sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
    </div>
    <div id="divThatYouWantAllOf" style="float:right" >
    This is why I hate web programming.
    </div>
```