# How to place two divs side by side where one sized to fit and other takes up remaining space?

Tags: html, overflow, css-float

This should be easy... why is this not easy?

I am looking to have 2 divs side by side, where one div will auto size to the content inside and the second div will simply fill the remaining width.  I need the text in the 'remaining width' div to be truncated if it is too large though, as I can only have these divs occupy one line.

I have been searching all day and the closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977872/css-two-divs-side-by-side-one-takes-up-as-much-room-as-need-other-fills-rest) post which suggested using tables that STILL didn't fix the issue.

Here is the jsfiddle code that reproduces my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ssawchenko/gMxWc/

I am hoping that one of you stack-peeps can help me out!

**=== CSS (Hacky) Solution? ===**

Apparently adding a negative margin (that must guarantee to be big enough to cover the right size) will "work". This seems so hacky and *may* not fix the issue completely though.   If I drag the jsfiddle window side to side to shrink and grow the divs, some oddities occur where the shrink-to text seems to float not on the complete right.

```
.right_part 
{
  margin-left:-1000px; 
  background:yellow;   
  float:right;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**=== Complete CSS Solution ===**

FINALLY found the right CSS combination!

http://jsfiddle.net/ssawchenko/gKnuY/

My mistake was I was incorrectly floating my "fit to" content.  By moving the div to the correct location in the DOM the content is floated correctly, and the "remaining sized" div will now correctly take up the remaining space.

I also wanted to force the divs to occupy ONE line, which is why I have set such strict CSS on the "remaining sized" div content.
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: Hackish or not, that's a really neat solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
#full_width_div {
    background-color:#5B8587;
    width:100%;
}
.left_part {
    background:red;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.right_part {
   background:yellow;   
   float:right;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="full_width_div">
  <div class="right_part">
     Size to fit me completely
  </div>
  <div class="left_part">
     I am long and should be truncated once I meet up with the size to me text.
  </div>    

  <div style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

My mistake was I was incorrectly floating my "fit to" content. By moving the div to the correct location in the DOM the content is floated correctly, and the "remaining sized" div will now correctly take up the remaining space.

I also wanted to force the divs to occupy ONE line, which is why I have set such strict CSS on the "remaining sized" div content. overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: maybe cut your solution from question and post it here, in your answer ;) It will be clearer.

Comment: "This should be easy... why is this not easy?" Literally laughed this morning. "Because CSS!" Nice solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you buddy.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#full_width_div, #full_width_div table {
    background-color:#5B8587;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left_part {
    background:red;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.right_part {
   background:yellow;  
   white-space:nowrap;
   verticle-align: top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="full_width_div">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_part" valign="top">I am long and should be truncated once I meet up with the size to me text.</td>
            <td class="right_part" valign="top">Size to fit me completely</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your working jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/gMxWc/68/

Comment: That works as well, thank you! Although you lose the ability to show text-ellipsis due to forcing the height of the table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery and code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    redraw();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    redraw();
});

function redraw()
{
    var full_width = $('body').width();
    var left_width = $('.left_part').width();
    $('.right_part').width(full_width - left_width );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMxWc/62/ - here is working example

Comment: That would work as well, although I was hoping for a purely CSS solution as I will have to apply something like this to many divs.  It's possible, it's just more prone to future issues.  Thank you for the suggestion - if my above hack fails I will fall back to jquery.