# Align 2 divs where right content is sized to fit and left is truncated

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 2 divs where the right content is fixed and the left is truncated to fill the remaining space.  I found this [How to place two divs side by side where one sized to fit and other takes up remaining space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046819/how-to-place-two-divs-side-by-side-where-one-sized-to-fit-and-other-takes-up-rem) (fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ssawchenko/gKnuY/) which is close, but I'd like the right div to not be floated right so if the text is small enough to fit the text appears side by side.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That seems a crazy way to do it up there. Tell if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/gKnuY/404/

The css:

```
.fixed {  
   float:right;
   width: 200px;
}​

.fluid {
    margin-right: 200px; /* same as fixed's width */
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="fluid"></div>
```

Comment: So the div on the right needs to be sized to the content so I am not able to set it's width to a fixed value.  Really both divs have variable length content but the div on the left I want truncated should it take too much space

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the last part. How close is this to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/gKnuY/405/

Comment: I think the problem is that I have not given all of the information.  So this is an ExtJS app that I had tried to simplify and have simplified far too much.  So this fiddle is a better representation of what I am dealing with from a pure HTML perspective http://jsfiddle.net/jej2003/eX9U7/ this gives me exactly the results that I want, but I don't like the 77% (really just done from visual inspection) width that is on the wrapping element because if the panel is resized things don't look right.  Thanks for all of the help so far!

Comment: so I ended up using a separate column for the information and this works pretty well.  Really not exactly what I wanted since the width of the second column may not be sufficient to fit the count, but I am not sure there is a better way to accomplish this in Ext, but I'd love to hear otherwise.

Comment: It's a little bit late here, where I'm at. I'll come back to this tomorrow.